# SassError: Expected newline. @charset "UTF-8"; when building a Vue app with Sass as sass-loader on Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to build my Vue app on Node 13 and Webpack 4. For this I'm using this webpack.config.js

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const path = require("path");
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: "./src/main.js",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash:12].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash:12].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test : /\.(jsx?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|txt)(\?\S*)?$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name][contenthash:8].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webm|mp4|svg|ico)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name][contenthash:8].[ext]",
          outputPath: "assets/img",
          esModule: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s(c|a)ss)$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 2,
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: () => [autoprefixer()],
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              implementation: require("sass"),
              sassOptions: {
                //fiber: require("fibers"),
                prependData: `@import "app/javascript/manager/styles/main.scss"`,
                //indentedSyntax: true
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
      chunkFilename: "[name].[contenthash:8].css",
    }),
    new htmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico"),
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: "vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js",
    },
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".css", ".scss", ".vue"],
    modules: [
      "node_modules",
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: "hashed",
    runtimeChunk: "single",
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: -10,
          chunks: "all",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
}
```

And this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.6",
    "webpack-war-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-alpha.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "sass": "1.32.13",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.1",
    "vue-loader": "^16.3.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.5.6",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

After struggling with the sass-loader I reduced the list of errors, but this one is significant and I haven't found a way to remove it:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/main.sass)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected newline.
  ╷
1 │ @charset "UTF-8";
  │                 ^
  ╵
```

No sass-node, just sass was used. Uncommenting indentedSyntax: true will simply drop another error saying that semicolons are not allowed. Upgrading versions will return other set of error. Fibers is out of scope (it just improves processing of certain async calls to my knowledge). Upgrading to Webpack5 adds a pletora of new problems as the json structure is quite different.

I'm totally stack at this point. There must be something else to work on the sass loader nut I'm not an expert on webpack so it's taking simply too long. Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point. I cannot believe none is having the same issue. I see many related answers but everyone seem to be doing fine just adding indentation. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear how your project uses `webpack.config.js`, but Vue CLI uses Webpack under the hood, so you don't need to provide your own Webpack config. You shouldn't need to provide any special config to uses Sass (installing `sass` and `sass-loader` is enough).

Comment: To tune better the way we pack we prefer to run a npm run compile instead of a build. If you can help that would be greatly appreciated